# How to get previous clicked element on any click event in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make an single selection in my app. I have a grid and inside it some images. When I clicked an image its parent which is a div background color change to red. I describe this event it is selected. I want to make deselect previous item when click any where. if clicked image is one of my item then new item should be selected and previous should be unselected. if clicked element is not one of my items just previus should be unselected. When I select an item then clicked one of the others it is working. However when I selected an item then click out of my items it is not working. In this stuation my `prevClickedElement` parameter refers to previous of previous clicked element. And I have no idea why state empty when update it in `clickElement` in context and in `removePrevSelectedSquare` in `Piece` component. Because of my app has multiple components and images I added to [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/single-selected-1vmp3?file=/src/Piece.js). I am not sure this is the correct way. Because when I select an item component created items count times in this case 15. This is a performance problem?

Comment: my solution is that using `array.map()` to render your component and  `useState` to save your selected item. and when you click a item the component will re-render, and then comparing each array element to selected one in state. if equal then change the background color otherwise no change

Comment: Could you share implementation?

Comment: When use `useState` previous state is lost because of component recreated on clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good approach would be creating a component global state to save the current element unique id and creating a function to set the element id when it is clicked. After that you can create a function that reset this state whenever it is called and implement this function as an DOM event in a superior div, the parent of the images. Here is the ideia in form of a code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';

function Stackoverflow(props) {
    const [selectedPicture, setSelectedPicture] = React.useState(null);
    function resetSelectedPicture() {
        setSelectedPicture(null)
    }    
    return (
        <div onClick={resetSelectedPicture}>
            {pictures.map((picture, index) => {
                const {id, src} = picture;
                return (
                    <>
                        <img
                            src={src} 
                            key={index} 
                            id={id}
                            className={
                                selectedPicture.id === id
                                    ? 'selected-picture'
                                    : 'unselected-picture'
                            }
                            onClick={setSelectedPicture(
                                () => picture
                            )}
                        />
                    </>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Stackoverflow;
```